# `ratpoison` doesn't accept cyrillic key commands

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, ratpoison

After I switch my keyboard layout to cyrillic

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,bg(phonetic)" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

`ratpoison` stops recognising keys and only states

```
readkey: Unbound key: Cyrillic_tse
```

However when I switch to a terminal and press the same key, `ц` is typed and that has been bound in `~/.ratpoisonrc`:

```
# ~/.ratpoisonrc
# Minimal config file for ratpoison.

# Meta key - Windows key.
# Press before command, not simultaneously.

# Basic commands:
# s, S - split screen into "frames"
# <space> - within a frame, cycle the "windows" open inside it
# <tab> - next frame
# c - create a terminal window in the current frame 
# r - resize this frame
# o - only frame - destroy all other frames
# R - remove current frame
# Q - quit ratpoison

escape Super_L

unbind Q
bind Q quit
bind o only

set startupmessage 0

bind Я quit
bing о only
bind к kill
bind ц exec xterm
bind с split
bind С hsplit
```

Comment: One of your `bind` commands says ``bing``,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'Cyrillic_tse' ( as per the popup message ) in .ratpoisonrc file instead of unicode character, that might work.